# error key "xxx...xxx" could not be looked up remotely on ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, arm

I'm trying to install gnome on ArchLinux ARM, which runs in a UTM virtual machine using `pacman -S gnome`. It's showing me the list of packages that need to be installed, I accept the installation. After it shows that I wrote in the code section and holds up for an answer. If I type n, it shows me this choosing again.

```
:: Import PGP key 77193F152BDBE6A6, "Arch Linux ARM Build System <builder+n1@archlinuxarm.org>"? [Y/n] y
error: key "77193F152BDBE6A6" could not be looked up remotely
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There quite a few Arch Linux forum postings for this issue. In one case the root cause was related to the system date, but mostly it seems to be just a question of refreshing the keys. Here's a few threads with solutions:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193382
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201804
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232676
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256820

In general I'd suggest getting familiar with Arch forums, wiki and other documentation. They seem to be very good. I don't even use Arch or any of its variants, but quite often when I search for solutions I find them there. They're even referenced a lot in my own distro's community.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me after running:

```
pacman-key --init

pacman-key --populate archlinuxarm
```

According to the [Package Signing on Archlinux Arm wiki](https://archlinuxarm.org/about/package-signing), turns out the need of verifying the master keys with special `archlinuxarm` instead of `archlinux`, please view the page above for standard configuration to enable signature checking in ArchLinux ARM.

Comment: This is the correct answer for arm arch linux